# How to remove a XMLNode from XMLDocument occuring at multiple nested levels

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xmlnode

I have a XML which has a node which kind of gets repeated across multiple levels in the file using C#.

Example of the XML:

```
<books>
    <book>
        <title>The Walking Dead</title>
        <author>Test Name</author>
        <isbn>1239859895</isbn>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>The Walking Dead</title>
        <author>
            <isbn>29893893893</isbn>
            <firstname>test1</firstname>
            <lastname>test</lastname>
        </author>
    </book>        
</books>
```

I want to remove all *isbn* nodes from this XMLdocument irrespective of its location.

Comment: Your question is too vague as we do not know what strategy you are using for the rest of your XML work. It would be better if we could give you an answer that fits your current project. We also do not know if this XML is a string or a file.

Comment: Your XML is a little broken.  `<lastname>test</test>` should be `<lastname>test</lastname>`

Comment: I can use either of XDocument or XMLDocument.

Comment: Fixed the XML to have the correct node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use XDocument instead of XmlDocument. Use .Descendants() to find all Nodes of a specific name/type. Then .Remove() them.

```
string xml = @"<books>
     <book>
         <title>The Walking Dead</title>
         <author>Test Name</author>
         <isbn>1239859895</isbn>
     </book>
     <book>
         <title>The Walking Dead</title>
         <author>
             <isbn>29893893893</isbn>
             <firstname>test1</firstname>
             <lastname>test</lastname>
         </author>
     </book>        
 </books>";

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
xdoc.Descendants("isbn").Remove();
string result = xdoc.ToString();
```

But if you want to go with XmlDocument use this code:

```
 XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmldoc.LoadXml(xml);
 foreach (var node in new  List<XmlNode>(xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("isbn")
                                         .OfType<XmlNode>()).Where(
                                         x => x.ParentNode != null))
 {
     node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);                      
 }

 string result = xmldoc.OuterXml;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you indicated that you are working with an [`XmlDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you need to remove a child `XmlElement` node via the [`RemoveChild`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.removechild%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method on the parent node:

```
    string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
        <books>
            <book>
                <title>The Walking Dead</title>
                <author>Test Name</author>
                <isbn>1239859895</isbn>
            </book>
            <book>
                <title>The Walking Dead</title>
                <author>
                    <isbn>29893893893</isbn>
                    <firstname>test1</firstname>
                    <lastname>test</lastname>
                </author>
            </book>        
        </books>
        ";
    // Initialize and load the XmlDocument
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);

    // Delete all XmlElements named "isbn".
    var list = doc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("isbn").OfType<XmlElement>().ToArray();
    foreach (var element in list)
    {
        var parent = element.ParentNode;
        if (parent != null)
            parent.RemoveChild(element);
    }
    var newXml = doc.OuterXml;
    Debug.WriteLine(newXml);
```

And the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<books>
  <book>
    <title>The Walking Dead</title>
    <author>Test Name</author>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>The Walking Dead</title>
    <author>
      <firstname>test1</firstname>
      <lastname>test</lastname>
    </author>
  </book>
</books>
```